# Does Halo Infinite Multiplayer have blood or not?

Tags: halo-infinite

I get very mixed perceptions from the internet as to whether the multiplayer has blood or not.  I've seen gameplay and all I saw was electric shocks and the holographs on the armor blinking ,didn't notice any blood.  If there is blood, can someone show a gif/video of it from a gameplay video?

Also, if there is blood, is there a setting to toggle it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multiplayer does not have blood. The most "gruesome" thing would be spartans 'disintegrating' after being killed by a Hardlight weapon, but no red blood anywhere.

Comment: apparently i forgot to select this answer a long time ago.  My bad.